# Entity Framework no connection string but it is there?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

Hello I've just started with entity and made model from database, but when I do my select it gives the following error:

> No connection string named 'ninja_crmEntities' could be found in the
>   application config file.

the project with entity is library class and the app.config looks like:

```
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
   <section name="entityFramework" 
            type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
            requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<entityFramework>
   <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
   <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
   </providers>
</entityFramework>
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ninja_crmEntities" 
        connectionString="metadata=res://*/ninja_entities.csdl|res://*/ninja_entities.ssdl|res://*/ninja_entities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=ninja_crm;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=elo320;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
        providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Make sure this config exists in directory where application runs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the project is a library, it doesn't use it's own App.config, but the one in the project that is actually executed. Are the EF settings in that config as well?

Comment: That should be a comment to question

Comment: Why? It provides an answer to the question.

Comment: I think no because its web -> bl -> dal and dal got only the app.config settings for entity should i implement in all projects the app.config ?

Comment: @Alex: You only need the config in the web project. Bear in mind that web projects use a config file called Web.config. It should already be there, so just add the EF config to that file.

Comment: Yes but how to translate app.config into webconfig?

Comment: You don't need to translate. Just add the exact same xml (without removing any of the existing lines, of course).